# Android 4.2 setOnMenuItemClickListener is not called

Tags: java, android, mobile, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I have an issue with the action bar on Android 4.2 with ActionBarSherlock. I have added an action bar menu item and it uses setOnMenuItemClickListener to set the buttons action.

```
    MenuItem mapButton = menu.findItem(R.id.show_map);

    mapButton.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

            //Button implementation goes here
        }
    });
```

This works fine on Android 2.2 up to Android 4.1 however on Android 4.2 onMenuItemClick does not get called at all.

I have tried adding this

```
//Handles the map and route button in the options bar 
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.show_map:
        return false;
    case R.id.show_route:
        return false;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Which does get called on button press but appears to have no effect. I could move the code the button implements into this function but it would require me to make drastic alterations to other parts of the program. Is there some way to get setOnMenuItemClickListener working on Android 4.2?